# How to find records with no photos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two table  `1. Artist` and  `2. Photo` that have `one to many` relationship.

I want to find `all artists` that have `no photos` and `less then 5 photos`.

How can I write query for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
Artist.join(:photos).having("count(photos.*)<5")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find those using this

```
Artist.join(:photos).group("photos.artist_id").select("sum(photos.artist_id) as total_photos").having("total_photos<5")
```